# Private parameterless constructor for the sake of the new property-based initialization

Tags: c#

I have read in the book "C# in Depth" that:

> private parameterless constructor is used for the sake of the new property-based initialization. In the example below, we could’ve actually removed the public constructor completely, but then no outside code could’ve created other product instances.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Product
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }

    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    Product() { }

    public static List<Product> GetSampleProducts()
    {
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Name = "West Side Story", Price = 9.99m },
            new Product { Name = "Assassins", Price = 14.99m },
            new Product { Name = "Frogs", Price = 13.99m },
            new Product { Name = "Sweeney Todd", Price = 10.99m }
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Price);
    }
}
```

But having said above I am able to create new object like

```
List<Product> ls = Product.GetSampleProducts();
            Product o = new Product("a",2);
            ls.Add(o);
            listBox1.DataSource = ls;
```

Without actually having a private parameterless constructor. Can anyone put some light on it?

Comment: @jon-skeet It would be great if you can put some light on the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize the object like that:

```
 Product o = new Product( "a" , 2);
```

***Because, it is not calling the parameterless constructor.*** Why?

> A constructor that takes no parameters is called a parameterless constructor or default
>   constructor. Default constructors are invoked whenever an object is
>   instantiated by using the `new` operator and ***no arguments are
>   provided*** to new.

The above code calls `public Product(string name, decimal price)` constructor and as you seen it is ***public***.

And after all, the author talks about ***new property-based initilization***. It means that:

```
Product product = new Product { Column1 = "col1", Column2 = "col2" };
```

When initializing object like that, ***public parameterless constructor*** will be called firstly.

And the above code is just a ***syntactic sugar*** for that:

```
Product product = new Product(); // Compiler error in outside while default constructor is private
product.Column1 = "col1"; // Compiler error in outside while the set accessor is private
product.Column2 = "col2"; // Compiler error in outside while the set accessor is private
```

Comment: Thanks Farhad. But when I have tried property based initializer. The private parameter constructor is of no use and when I tried making it public it gives "The property or indexer cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

Comment: Above comment states that in above code setter should be public as well. What do you say?

Comment: @hellowahab Everything is OK. You have made the `set` accessors private. It means, that they are readonly in the outside of this class.

Comment: Yes I know but setting an accessor private wouldn't allow the property based initialization as well.

Comment: @hellowahab Exactly. While set accessor is private you can not set the value to this property in the outside of this class. But, you can call any public constructor which will set the values.

Answer (score 1):

Property-based initialization mandates existence of a parameterless constructor. As @farhad-jabiyev has already correctly stated that property-based initialization e.g.

```
Product product = new Product { Name = "West Side Story", Price = 9.99m };
```

is just syntactic sugar for code which looks like this:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "West Side Story";
product.Price = 9.99m;
```

If you comment the private parameterless constructor in the example code provided in the question, you will get a compilation error:

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter         'name' of 'Product.Product(string, decimal)'

which means C# compiler tries to invoke the parameterless constructor to create an instance of Product class before assigning the property values. Hope it helps.